# app.get() method does not appear to get called in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to MEAN stack and am trying to implement express.  For some reason, I am getting a 404 when navigating to a path that I have set up the app object to handle.  I know that the app must be running, because the error is being handled by a custom method I put in to handle 404's.

[image]

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongoose');


var db = mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/recipedb", function (err, response) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  else { console.log('Connected to ' + db, ' + ', response) }
});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: 'Smb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var Schema = mongo.Schema;

var categorySchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: String },
  name: { type: String }
}, {versionKey: false});

var cModel = mongo.model('category', categorySchema, 'category');


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET','POST','OPTIONS','PUT','PATCH','DELETE',);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.get("test", function (req, res) {

  res.send('The GET Request was handled by express');

  
})

app.get("category", function (req, res) {


  model.find({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);

    }

    else {
      res.send(data);
    }

  });
}

) 


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Unable to find the requested resource!');
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Rapid Recipes listening on port 3000...');
}
  )
```

Comment: how about you put "/test" instead of "test" in app.get() ?

Comment: You need to put `/` in front! Use `/test`.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue. I thought I wouldn't need the / because  in my http client, I am including the / after the hostname when sending the request.  It makes sense though that the character gets dropped when received by express.

Comment: @MarcusSantodonato That was exactly my first answer I wrote an hour ago. Check out the answers! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `app.get('/test',function (req, res) { ... your code ...})`
same for category ... you forget "/" at the begining of the URL